# Chrome adding UA stylesheets to my sites

Tags: css, google-chrome

For some reason, Chrome on my computer's been adding some weird user agent stylesheets to all my sites, leading to some weird formatting (for example, header > h1 doesn't have any letter spacing). You can see some of the user agent stylesheets being applied here:

[image]

I have confirmed that this problem is only on my computer, and no other computers have problems viewing these sites. I don't have any extensions installed.

How do I disable/remove these stylesheets?

Comment: Have you tried a CSS reset stylesheet?

Comment: Yup, the website stylesheet includes a reset stylesheet.

Comment: Chrome provides a user styles style sheet, have you placed anything in there? There are also plugins which do the same thing, are you running the Stylish extension from http://userstyles.org ?

Comment: Where is `letter-spacing` in your screenshot? The user agent CSS I can see in your screenshot is all normal and as it should be. Can you demonstrate with screenshots and/or a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) what you're talking about? What version of Chrome?

Comment: @meagar, no, I haven't added anything to the user styles sheet (AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets). I checked it, and it seems to be empty.

Comment: @thirtydot Good point, but if I forcefully set the letter-spacing, the headings have the letter-spacing appear. Also, the problem isn't with my code/CSS, as I have the same problem on 3rd party sites: http://imgur.com/XvYIE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot:

[image]

The problem is not `letter-spacing` (as in, the CSS property). It has nothing at all to do with CSS.

That font on your computer is screwed up, you need to find a new version of it.

Comment: BINGO! Gah, can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks!